Resistor connected to comparator non-inverting input

I came across such a circuit.
When a voltage above 0 is applied to the noniverting input, the output remains at 3.3v. So far, normal.
When I pull the input directly to gnd in the pspice simulation, the input continues to remain at 3.3v.
A trick is made here, a 330kohm R37 resistor is attached. Then, when it is pulled to gnd via 330k, the noniverting input appears negative. For this reason, the output is pulled to the low output state and I see a value like 20mV.
I have not come across such a structure before. Is the purpose of r37 here to pull the output low when 0V input comes?



The simulator or model is faulty. In a circuit with 0V and positive supply, it is impossible that current goes into a comparator, developing a negative input voltage over a resistor.

Input bias current of the simulated LMV331 may be incorrect. Looking at the LMV331 internals, the input circuitry consists of PNP bipolar transistors, and I would expect those inputs to therefore source a tiny amount of current if they had similar potentials. The datasheets says it's typically 15nA, which would develop 5mV or so across a 330kΩ resistor, the comparator-input-end of that resistor having the higher potential:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In other words, if you tied node A to ground, as shown, the comparator's non-inverting input would have a potential above ground by about 5mV, which would cause the output to remain high. Node A would have to be taken to -5mV (maybe even a bit lower, since the LM393 inputs probably exhibit a little hysteresis) to bring the output low.
That's not your experience with the simulator, though. If the simulated LMV331 is not displaying this behaviour, and it permits you to alter input bias current, then you should specify -15nA, to see if that changes anything.
If the LMV331 is anything like the LM393, it isn't too fussed about input potentials somewhat exceeding the positive supply, but it will begin to source a lot of input current (maybe milliamps) if those inputs fall below the negative supply, which could damage the device, and will certainly be operating the comparator outside its acceptable input voltage range limits. Perhaps this design is expected to have strongly negative potentials applied at A, and it's possible that the resistor is there to limit input current when that occurs, and prevent the non-inverting input leaving the bounds of acceptable input voltages.

The LMV331 is not like the '393.  Unlike the latter, which can accept more than 35V on the inputs regardless of Vcc, the inputs are clamped to the supply rails and the absolute maximum voltage is  (inconveniently) stated in the datasheet as Vcc. However, in a support forum post a TI representative ventures that if current is limited to 10mA it should be okay.
